# How can I use the input from a JOptionPane.showInputDialog to be used as a message?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, input, joptionpane

So, I need to take the input I get from (for example)

```
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "text");
```

(and if the user enters some text, say, "hello" it would be used as a message in

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
```

I think I have to use a variable like:
        variable=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "text");

but how do I connect the two and what type will the variable have?

Comment: So, you're using Swing without knowing how to use variables? That's like driving a Boeing without knowing the difference between left and right. Start with the basics. Read an introductory Java or even programming book or tutorial, and don't touch Swing until you're comfortable with basic OO stuff (which should come after basic programming stuff).

Comment: Please choose the correct answer and close the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can add it in one line,

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter a message"));
```

Or, you can create a string to hold a message:

```
String message =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a message");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message);
```

Note that first parameter may be `null`, in which case a default Frame is used as the parent, and the dialog will be centered on the screen (depending on the L&F).

Read about [**`JOptionPane`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Answer (score 3):

Read the Oracle docs on [variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). Then consult the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) for JOptionPane

```
String message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "text");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

Answer (score 3):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Provide Input");` This statement returns String value which can be use to pass in `showMessageDialog`. Refer below code

```
String ans=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give some input");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ans);
```